# Why doesn't Vue Event Propagate Up?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

When emitting an event from a child component, why doesn't the containing app catch the event? See the code below for a very basic example. When clicking one of the links, I would expect an alert for "app" followed by an alert for "component". Instead, it only gives "component".

```js
Vue.component('list-item', {
  template: '<li><a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="itemClick">click</a></li>',
  methods: {
    itemClick() {
      this.$emit('item-event');
      alert('component');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      'a', 'b', 'c'
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    itemClick: function() {
      alert('app');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" v-on:item-event="itemClick">
  <ol>
    <li is="list-item" v-for="item in items"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

If this is not the proper to way to communicate from children up to parents, what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue events are not bubbling up in the DOM tree. You need to listen on the event on your `list-item` component which is emitting the event:

```js
Vue.component('list-item', {
  template: '<li><a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="itemClick">click</a></li>',
  methods: {
    itemClick() {
      this.$emit('item-event');
      alert('component');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [
      'a', 'b', 'c'
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    itemClick: function() {
      alert('app');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li is="list-item" v-for="item in items" v-on:item-event="itemClick"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. You just saved me a lot of frustration.